# LibreOffice 5 Bootstrap.bootstrap throws ExternalException with error code -2147467259

Tags: c#, c++, exception, external, libreoffice

I wrote a C# .dll for LibreOffice in LibreOffice 4 and had it compiling and running fine. I downloaded LibreOffice 5 and got the plugin working with that as well. I did some things that seem like they must be red herrings, and now when I try to call Bootstrap.bootstrap() it returns an ExternalException with the message "External component has thrown an exception." My hunch is that bootstrap can't find the LibreOffice install, but it has worked fine in the past.

The stack trace looks like this

`at cppu.bootstrap(Reference<com::sun::star::uno::XComponentContext>*)
at uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap()
at LibreOfficePlug.Office.getPDF(String fileURL)
in C:\\projects\\zbuildsrc\\LibreOfficePlug\\Office.cs:line 20`

Office.cs is the name of the class, getPDF is the function that takes a URL and converts it to a PDF

The .dll still compiles fine, and I can still access the function from the main project, but when it calls Bootstrap.bootstrap() it throws an exception in the LibreOffice code, so I don't know how to dig to the root of the problem. The project that I'm calling the dll from is in C++ but I wrote this dll in C# if that makes a difference.

The things that I did that I'm pretty sure are red herrings are as follows (these all happened after I successfully used the dll with libreoffice 5)

I noticed that the folder I was storing my dll in was nested inside of another folder of the same name (i.e. LibreOfficePlug/LibreOfficePlug/[project files]), so I went to move the project files into the upper folder and delete the extraneous folder. When I did that, the .sln I'm using that has the main project and the dlls I use was unable to find the LibreOfficePlug project (because I moved it). So I removed the project from the .sln and attempted to re-add it. At first I accidentally just added the LibreOfficePlug .sln file to the main project resource files, but I deleted it from there and added the LibreOfficePlug project to the solution properly. Again, these things all seem like they're probably unrelated but I figured I'd recount the events that lead to it breaking, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same problem. What I have done is to copy the LibreOffice 4 URE folder into current LibreOffice 5 folder. After this it works fine. You can try this out.